# Does there exist such a set?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

$R$ is a set of real numbers, m is the Lebesgue measure on $R$.

Does exist a nowhere dense subset $A\subseteq R $, such that $m(A)=+\infty$?

I know that if $A$ is of the first category, there exist such a set.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) is nowhere dense, has measure $1/2$ and is a subset of the unit interval $[0,1]$.  If you take the union of the translates of this set by the integers, you will get a nowhere dense set that is of infinite measure.

Comment: you will get a nowhere dense set"——Why this set is still a nowhere dense set, and this set is closed in R?

Comment: @David: Yes, it’s closed: it’s the union of a locally finite family of closed sets. Its complement is therefore open, and its complement is obviously dense, so this set must be nowhere dense.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Well, I have known why. A perfect answer! A wonderful explanation!